# Show/Hide ListView from activity

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I want to toggle the visibility of a `ListView` through a button but as I am using `@android:id/list` for the ListView I don’t know how to retrieve the view in Activity through `findViewById(R.id. list);`:

For that I have the following code:

```
public void feedButtonListener() {

    final ImageButton ToggleButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ToggleFeed);

    ToggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Toggleis clicked!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list); //HOW?
            if (feedView) {
                listView.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                ToggleButton
                        .setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_inactive);
                feedView = false;
            } else {
                listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ToggleButton
                        .setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_active);
                feedView = true;

            }
        }

    });
```

And in Layout:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin" >
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list); //thats how :)
```

Note the android in front: **android**.R.id.list

If you're in a `ListFragment` or `ListActivity` you can just call

```
ListView listView = getListView();
```